# Convert an simple IntelliJ project with JUnit tests init into Maven or Gradle project

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, guava, jetbrains-ide

I wanna if it's easy to convert a simple IntelliJ project to a Maven or Gradle project

I was writing a program and I'm using JUnit tests and wanna use Guava or Apash common tools for a bidirectional hashmap and it is easier to integrate it with Maven or Gradle I tried but I got many errors I followed the procedure in the link below. I created the gradle and settings files and when I want to run a test I'm getting this error: !!! JUnit version 3.8 or later I tried my best to search and reconfigure things but it did not work I tried so hard ... what can I do?
If someone can help I have the project in my GitHub.
The procedure I followed:  [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#:~:text=Convert%20a%20regular%20project%20into,gradle%20and%20click%20OK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#:%7E:text=Convert%20a%20regular%20project%20into,gradle%20and%20click%20OK).

if there is someone who can help me, please.

I search to integrate Guava or Apash common tools in my project.

UPDATE: I managed to download all the .jar dependencies I needed and added them directly to my Java project

Comment: I would suggest following a tutorial on Maven or Gradle without relying on IDE support. To learn and understand it is important to look at one system at a time. Or you will not understand their interaction, nor the cause of any problems that may occur.

Comment: Where is the source code link on the GitHub?

Comment: @JackyLiu i make it private cause sorry but i updated my status about my issue

Comment: Please update the link, I can't see it...